# How to make a div fill the remaining space of an absolute bottom div

Tags: html, css

I'm actually having 2 divs that are superimposed in a parent container. The second div is absolute and is set to the bottom of the container. I want now to make the first div's height fill the remaining upper space left by the absolute one. I've looked it up but only found solutions to when the absolute div is at the top and not at the bottom. How should I do it ?

```css
.container {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}
#row1 {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}  
#row2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="row1"> Row 1 content </div>
   <div id="row2"> Row 2 content </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code snippet for more clarity: https://jsfiddle.net/ekm7y1nz/

EDIT: I'm afraid the row2 has to be absolute because I shouldn't have to scroll down to see it if the row1's content is too long for example. Only row1 should be scrollable if it's too long.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd just go the flex route instead. Cheers

```css
.container {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
}
#row1 {
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}  
#row2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="row1"> Row 1 content </div>
   <div id="row2"> Row 2 content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is the second div has to be absolute because it has to stick to the bottom i.e i shouldn't scroll down to see it if the first div's content is too long for example

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is just scrolling you can change row1's css to this :

```
#row1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

the page will scroll when text gets bigger than it's div parent.

alse you can set row2's div height based on row1 with js or css frameworks like sass if your interested in using them.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that if I set row1's height to 100%, some content will be hidden behind row2 since it's absolute

Comment: Does your element's height is persistant?